# Can mysqldump dump triggers and procedures?

Tags: mysql, backup, stored-procedures, trigger, mysqldump

Is there any way of making a mysqldump which will save all the triggers and procedures from a specified db?

Some time ago I read that `mysqldump` will also save my triggers, but it doesn't look like it. My second related question is how can I check in a sql file if triggers exists?

Answer (score 16):

I normally do not separate triggers from the tables they were meant for. I dump like this:

```
mysqldump -u... -p... --no-data --routines --triggers dbname > DBSchema.sql
```

Check for presence of routines and triggers like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM mysql.proc;

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.triggers;

SELECT * FROM information_schema.triggers\G
```

If you want to get this done to all DBs in the MySQL Instance, do this:

```bsh
mysql -u... -p... -A -N -e"SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql')" > /tmp/dblist.txt
for DB in `cat /tmp/dblist.txt`
do
    mysqldump -u... -p... --no-data --no-create-info --routines dbname > ${DB}-routines.sql
    mysqldump -u... -p... --no-data --triggers dbname > ${DB}-schema-triggers.sql
done
```

That way, stored procedures go in a routines dump for the DB, while the schema and triggers go in another dump.

Comment: @dole Rolando's right on how to dump triggers/procedures. If you want to see if they exist in a sql file, open it and search for 'CREATE TRIGGER' calls. If in *nix, `grep 'CREATE TRIGGER'`

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA, Isn't [`--triggers`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_pipe) dumped by default? What would be the difference between `--no-data --routines --triggers` vs `--no-data --routines`?

Comment: @Pacerier There have been situations where I didn't want triggers and I would use `--skip-triggers` on such occasions (such as setting up slaves that didn't need the triggers). As a constant reminder to myself of the possibility of skipping options, I always use certain flags in mysqldumps (`--routines`, `--triggers`) even if they are default. So, it's just a personal preference. If you trust that a default setting will remain a default from version to version and never deal with adhoc situations, then you express the mysqldumps as needed as long as the resulting mysqldump is correct for you.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA - What do -A -N do?

Comment: I have used regular expressions to prepend DROP trigger statements: Replace this: (\/\*\!50003 CREATE\*\/ \/\*\!50017 DEFINER\=some_text_here\*\/\ /\*\!50003 TRIGGER (.*?) )

With this: DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `$2`;;\n$1

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful. I thought my basic dump was doing the job, and it wasn't. Everything was so mangled.

Comment: Found more infor on dumping GRANTS: mysql -u user -ppassword --skip-column-names -A -e"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ',QUOTE(user),'@',QUOTE(host),';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''" | mysql -u user -ppassword --skip-column-names -A | sed 's/$/;/g' > MySQLUserGrants.sql

Answer (score 1):

In my case adding `--triggers` was not enough. It has turned out that the user I was using to dump didn't have such a privilege in the DB.